# How to login into a remote machine and execute commands on it using csh script?

Tags: shell, csh

I am trying to execute this script. Whenever i try to rsh/rlogin to the machine, it stops the the script from executing and the commands that follow stop executing, please help.

```
#!/bin/csh -xvf

#####BUILDING####
rlogin buildsub 
pushd $currdir/$currdate/ABC/src;
bsub -I make 64bit=yes dev=opt
```

Comment: Because the remote shell knows nothing about your local script? the commands after the rlogin will be executed (locally) when the rlogin finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your three commands are each executed separately on your local machine, one after another.  Your script doesn't know that the pushd and the bsub are supposed to be used as input to the rlogin.
To get round this, use a here doc:

```
rlogin buildsub  << END_BLOCK
pushd $currdir/$currdate/ABC/src;
bsub -I make 64bit=yes dev=opt
END_BLOCK
```